# Does Compose ConstraintLayout provide same handling for INVISIBLE and GONE as view based ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Disclaimer: I know that Compose just entered alpha01 and thus I do not expect that every functionality
is available. However, layout and handling of specific layout cases is IMHO an important topic
that should be addressed early .

The current *view based* `ConstraintLayout` provides some specific handling in case a child view is
marked as `GONE`, refer to the
[ConstrainLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#VisibilityBehavior).

I checked the *Compose* `ConstraintLayout` documentation, the available modifiers and so on, however
did not find anything that points in this direction. I also could not find any hint regarding
`INVISIBLE` and how/if *Compose* `ConstraintLayout` handles it like the *view based* `ConstraintLayout`.

In general, the current view based layouts (LinearLayout for example) handle `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` in a
similar fashion:

- if a view is in state `INVISIBLE` then the view is part of the layout with its sizes, just not
  shown. The overall layout of other views does not change and they stay in their positions.
- if a view is in state `GONE` its sizes a usually treated as 0 and the layout is recomputed and
  changed, other views usually change their positions.

Here a simple Compose ConstraintLayout UI, just 4 buttons in a row, chained to have them nicely
spread.

```
// if dontShow is 0 then show all buttons, otherwise make the button with this number
// somehow INVISIBLE. This feature is not yet implemented.
@Composable
fun fourButtonsCL(dontShow: Int) {
    ConstraintLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val (btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4) = createRefs()
        TextButton(onClick = {}, Modifier.constrainAs(btn1) {}.background(teal200)) { Text("Button1") }
        TextButton(onClick = {}, Modifier.constrainAs(btn2) {}.background(teal200)) { Text("Button2") }
        TextButton(onClick = {}, Modifier.constrainAs(btn3) {}.background(teal200)) { Text("Button3") }
        TextButton(onClick = {}, Modifier.constrainAs(btn4) {}.background(teal200)) { Text("Button4") }

        createHorizontalChain(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun previewThreeButtons() {
    ComposeAppTheme {
        fourButtonsCL()
    }
}
```

Assume I would like to make `Button3` invisible, but keep the other 3 buttons positioned where they
are. Thus just a hole between `Button2` and `Button4`. How to achieve this without creating yet another
Composable or adding additional logic. While the logic in this simple case may be just a view lines
of code, more complex layouts would the need some more complex logic. In veiw based ConstraintLayout
wwe just need to modify the child view.

The other assumption: make `Button3` disappear completely from the layout (`GONE`) and re-compute the
layout, remaining buttons become wider and evenly spread out. At a first glance this looks simple,
and in this very simple example it maybe easy. However in more complex layouts this could require
some or even a lot of re-wiring of constraints of the embedded Composables.

Thus the question is:
how does compose handles these cases for `Column` and `Row` layouts (like in view based LinearLayout)
and for `ConstraintLayout` in particular? However with the following restriction : without defining
many new Composables and/or without adding complex layout logic inside the Composables (re-wiring
constraints for example).

Did I miss some modifier? Is this even planned or possible in the Composable layouts? What would be
the preferred way to solve such layout cases in Compose?

Comment: "Invisible" and "gone" are not really things in Compose UI. "Gone" would be you simply not including the element in your composition, and you are in charge of the rules for that scenario as well as the cases where the element is in the composition. "Invisible" probably would be building the composition with a `Spacer()` or some other transparent alternative to the regular element, based upon your condition. I don't think that a `Modifier` can cause invisibility, as a `Modifier` decorates a composable more than it changes it.

Comment: That's what I thought / feared. On complex layouts this requires programming logic to exclude elements, re-wire constraints etc. I tested that already and it's ugly. I also used different Composables to avoid complex programming logic, however that leads to quite a lot of code duplication.
What was a simple statement to set a view to GONE or INVISIBLE now becomes a real complex task.

Comment: Since it is likely a year-plus before Compose ships in stable form, I would not draw any long-term conclusions from the current alphas. In terms of "invisible", I may have been overly pessimistic: try [`Modifier.drawOpacity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).drawOpacity(kotlin.Float)) with `0f` and see if that turns the composable transparent.

Comment: Thanks.
drawOpacity(0f) did the trick at least for the simple test case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @CommonsWare comment to the question I could solve the `INVISIBLE`
option, see code below.

Currently (in alpha-01) the implementation of ConstraintLayout seems to be incomplete, at least a few *TODO* comments in the code indicate this. This
seems to include the yet missing support of the `GONE` feature.
I saw some of these:

> // TODO(popam, b/158069248): add parameter for gone margin

Also the chain feature does not yet perform layout rendering in the same way as
in the view based ConstraintLayout.

```
object FourElementsNoDSL {
    const val elementA = "ElementA"
    const val elementB = "ElementB"
    const val elementC = "ElementC"
    const val elementD = "ElementD"

    private val noDSLConstraintSet = ConstraintSet {

        // Create references with defines ids, here using a string as id. Could be an Int as well,
        // actually it's defined as 'Any'
        val elemA = createRefFor(elementA)
        val elemB = createRefFor(elementB)
        val elemC = createRefFor(elementC)
        val elemD = createRefFor(elementD)

        // Simple chain only. Instead of this simple chain we can use (for example):
        //     constrain(elemA) {start.linkTo(parent.start) }
        // to set a constraint as known in XML

//        constrain(elemA) {start.linkTo(parent.start, 16.dp) }
//        constrain(elemB) {start.linkTo(elemA.end) }
//        constrain(elemC) {start.linkTo(elemB.end) }
//        constrain(elemD) {end.linkTo(parent.end) }
        createHorizontalChain(elemA, elemB, elemC, elemD)
    }

    @Composable
    fun fourButtonsCLNoDSL(doNotShow: List<String>) {
        ConstraintLayout(constraintSet = noDSLConstraintSet, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            // This block contains the children
            Text(text = "A",
                    modifier = Modifier.layoutId(elementA)
                            .drawOpacity(if (doNotShow.contains(elementA)) 0f else 1f)
                            .padding(0.dp),
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp)
            )
            Text(text = "B",
                    modifier = Modifier.layoutId(elementB)
                            .drawOpacity(if (doNotShow.contains(elementB)) 0f else 1f)
                            .padding(0.dp),
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp)
            )
            Text(text = "C",
                    modifier = Modifier.layoutId(elementC)
                            .drawOpacity(if (doNotShow.contains(elementC)) 0f else 1f)
                            .padding(0.dp),
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp)
            )
            Text(text = "D",
                    modifier = Modifier.layoutId(elementD)
                            .drawOpacity(if (doNotShow.contains(elementD)) 0f else 1f)
                            .padding(0.dp),
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp))

        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun previewFourFieldsNoDSL() {
    val noShow = listOf(FourElementsNoDSL.elementC)
    PlaygroundTheme {
        FourElementsNoDSL.fourButtonsCLNoDSL(noShow)
    }
}
```

The `object FourElementsNoDSL` defines the layout, provides element ids and so on.
This is roughly comparable to an XML file that contains such layout.
*noDSL* means, that this layout does not use the Compose ConstraintLayout's Kotlin
DSL. Currently the DSL does not provide a mechanism to setup element references
(used in `layoutId`) with defined ids as its done in this example.